# Linking SQL Server tables to a PostgreSQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2005, ssms, postgresql-9.3

I have a SQL Server 2005 instance and also a **PostgreSQL 9.3** running on the same network, I would like to know if its possible to somehow create or have 'views' on a database within the PostgreSQL server that show data coming from SQL Server.

Comment: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/FDW

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

- A foreign data wrapper like `odbc_fdw` or `tds_fdw` (see [foreign data wrappers list](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/FDW), [foreign data wrapper documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createforeigndatawrapper.html)); or
- [`dbi-link`](http://dbi-link.projects.pgfoundry.org/) - see [github repo](https://github.com/davidfetter/DBI-Link)

Comment: Have you successfully manage to get data from MSSQL into a pg db?. I installed `tds_fdw` but documentation its only useful until you install then there's nothing to guide you through how are you supposed to get the tables from MSSQL... (?)

Comment: @ZQL Once installed, you're supposed to follow the generic PostgreSQL documentation for foreign data wrappers I think. `CREATE FOREIGN DATA WRAPPER`, `CREATE SERVER`, `CREATE USER MAPPING` (if necessary), `CREATE FOREIGN TABLE`. See http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createforeigndatawrapper.html and the see-also links there.