# Foreign Data Wrappers & Windows Authentication

Tags: sql-server, postgresql-9.3, foreign-data

I been trying to get data from a SQL Server to use it on a PostgreSQL database. After a [previous question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/96380/linking-sql-server-tables-to-a-postgresql-server) I got into use **FOREIGN DATA WRAPPERS**, first I try with [`tds_fdw`](https://github.com/GeoffMontee/tds_fdw) but after a successfull install I couldn't make it work, possibly due to the same issue I detail below.

After this i went to [Multicorn](http://multicorn.org/) and things where a bit better since there actual documentation for the usage of it.

After attempting to add a table from SQL Server I got the message:

```
 ERROR:  Error in python: OperationalError DETAIL:  (OperationalError)
 SQL Server message 18456, severity 14, state 1, line 1: **Login failed
 for user 'postgres'**. DB-Lib error message 18456, severity 14: General
 SQL Server error: Check messages from the SQL Server DB-Lib error
 message 20002, severity 9: Adaptive Server connection failed
```

So I got it that its an authentication error, the SQL Server works with Windows Authentication so my connection string (`mssql+pymssql://postgres:postgres@10.0.0.10/ForeignDatabase`) its rendered useless. After some more search i got to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16955160/login-failed-using-check-mssql-server-py) answer:

> The check_mssql_server.py plugin will NOT work with Windows
>   Authentication and requires SQL authentication.
>
> As of this time I do not believe anyone has created a MSSQL plugin
>   that can use Windows Authentication.

Clearly not the same scenario but its also a Data wrapper operation giving a extremely similar error message.

So my question is: Is it true that there's no way of using a foreign data wrapper from PostgreSQL to SQL Server using **Windows Authentication**?. I did add a new user (`postgres:postgres`) to the SQL Server.

I will also like to add that the PostgreSQL 9.3 Server lives on an Ubuntu Server 14.04 and the SQL Server 2005 on a Windows Server 2003.

Comment: As far as I know you can never use Windows authentication if the client is not a Windows host either. For example: Microsoft only ships Windows DLLs for their JDBC driver to enable Windows authentication. Your Postgres server is the client (from SQL Server's point of view) and is connecting from a non-Windows OS. I think you will have a lot less headaches if you switch SQL Server to mixed authentication and use a SQL Server user for the FDW.

Comment: Yeah I'll think the same but switching authentication its not really my call, I thought there  might be a way around this...

Comment: It'd be quite tricky to support this I think. We'd probably have to have a way to tunnel the credentials request from the Windows server through the FDW and to the client, or we'd need some kind of proxy/delegation rights given to the PostgreSQL server so it can "act as" any user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, thanks to the guidance of the community I manage to got it to work... I believe its important for me to mention a few things you should take in account when attempting this (at least under the same environment I been trying).

**My setup:**

- Ubuntu 14.04 <-> PostgreSQL 9.3
- Windows Server 2003 <-> SQL Server 2005

**Additional components:**

- SQL Alchemy 0.9.9
- Multicorn 1.1.0

Im not gonna go into details on how to install this components since there's plenty of documentation online.

Once this is setup I took [a_horse_with_no_name](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/1822/a-horse-with-no-name) advice on changing SQL Server authentication to mixed authentication and created a new account, for the sake of the example I use `postgres:postgres`. Additionaly still on SSMS I defined `SELECT` permissions for user `postgres` in the table I wanted to get the data from `tblTest`.

Back in my PostgreSQL I created a new database (`pgTest`) and setup multicorn:

`CREATE EXTENSION multicorn;`

Created the server for our FOREIGN DATA WRAPPER:

```
CREATE SERVER alchemy_srv FOREIGN DATA WRAPPER multicorn options (
    wrapper 'multicorn.sqlalchemyfdw.SqlAlchemyFdw'
);
```

And then (what it was supposed to be the last step) create the table that is going to get data from MS SQL Server:

```
CREATE FOREIGN TABLE pgTable (LogTime varchar, 
                              LogUser varchar, 
                              LogData varchar) 
server alchemy_srv OPTIONS   (tablename 'tblTest', 
                           db_url 'mssql+pymssql://postgres:postgres@10.0.0.0/RemoteDBName');
```

This shows no error, but once you throw a simple `SELECT * FROM pgTable;` I was getting the error I [OP](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/96885/foreign-data-wrappers-windows-authentication) up there.

So I search a bit more and stumbled on [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/sqlalchemy/xl-K45VbdV0) Google Groups posts labeled on a response as a [BUG](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/pymssql/+bug/918896).

One of the [offered solutions](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/pymssql/+bug/918896/comments/5) is getting rid of pymssql, as in:

`apt-get uninstall python-pymssql; pip install pymssql`

After this I tried again to create the table and getting data but nothing happened, i was just getting a blank table.

So I `pip install pymssql --upgrade`, once again create the table within PostgreSQL and voila! this time worked perfect.

Hopefully this will help someone else in the future, thanks for your guidance!